# find all occurrences of html elements sequences

Tags: javascript, xpath, evaluate

XPath can find only childs `ev('.//div[@class="parent"]/div[@class="children"]');` , but not siblings sadly and I need to find all occurrences  of sequence:
`<div class="1"></div><div class="2"></div><div class="3">`

not when only one of those is present or they are present in the wrong order, what can you suggest to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether I interpret your boundary conditions correctly but in case you want to detect *exactly* the sequence with respect to `<div>` with potentially *other* tags in between you can use this expression:

```
.//div[@class='1' and (following-sibling::div)[1][@class = '2'] and ((following-sibling::div)[2][@class = '3'])]
```

This would return the occurences of `<div class='1'>`. Of course, you can easily change this to return the other occurences with `class='2'` or `class='3'`.

If you want to exclude the potential occurence of other tags in between you can use:

```
.//div[@class='1' and (following-sibling::*)[1][local-name()='div' and @class = '2'] and ((following-sibling::*)[2][local-name()='div' and @class = '3'])]
```